# Does anyone know how to space out console text for java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console, numbers, spacing

Excuse me if I sound ignorant in anyway. This is my first day learning Java and I have a problem. Everytime I run a program. This happens :

Eveytime i run my program, it reads  "53308.0of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is533.08Football Fields."
I don't know how to put spaces between the number "53308.08" and "of "  and also " 533.08" and Football
Is this how console text is supposed to be? Can i fix it ?

public class BreesPassingYardsFields {
    public static void main (String args []) {

```
double PassYards; // Number of career pass yards Drew Brees has.
double FieldLength; // Number of yards in a football field
double FootballFields; // The amount of football fields Drew Brees has thrown for

PassYards = 53308; // Start with Drew Brees' Pass Yards
FieldLength = 100; // Length of a football field
FootballFields = PassYards / FieldLength; // converts to how many Football Fields Drew Brees has thrown for

System.out.println(PassYards + "of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is" + FootballFields + "Football Fields");

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
System.out.println(PassYards + " of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is" + FootballFields + " Football Fields");
```

or you can do something like this:

```
System.out.format("%f of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is %f Football Fields", PassYards, FootballFields);
```

%f is format for double nad float, for int you would use %d, you can format the number with some options like %.3f etc. see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(PassYards + " of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is " + FootballFields + " Football Fields");
```

Just add spaces where needed to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as much spaces you wish by filling them in between you `"`.

`System.out.println(PassYards + "    of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is. " + FootballFields + "   Football Fields");`

Answer (score 0):

Put them like you did it in texts:

```
System.out.println(PassYards + " of Drew Brees' Pass Yards is " + FootballFields + " Football Fields");
```